Error Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
I'm trying to use the Grafana API to create an Organization but when perform the request with axios from the Vue componenet got the following error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8001/api/orgs. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

I've tried to config custom response headers on Grafana config file but the error still.
grafana.ini:
[server.custom_response_headers]
Access-Control-Allow-Origin = http://localhost:8005
Access-Control-Allow-Methods = *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers = Content-Type,Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials = true

Create.vue:
const customOptions = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  auth: {
    username: import.meta.env.VITE_GRAFANA_API_USER,
    password: import.meta.env.VITE_GRAFANA_API_PASSWORD
  },
  withCredentials: true
}

const data = {
  name: "Example name"
}

axios.post('http://localhost:8001/api/orgs', data, customOptions)
  .then((response) => {
    organization.value = response;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

Request headers:
OPTIONS /api/orgs HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8001
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:131.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/131.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Referer: http://localhost:8005/
Origin: http://localhost:8005
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Priority: u=4

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8005
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Date: Wed, 23 Oct 2024 07:37:34 GMT
Content-Length: 102

Any idea how to solve it?
Thanks

Grafana cannot be configured for CORS.

To be more accurate, you can set it up manually with the custom_headers parameters or use the recommended approach: a reverse proxy.

Grafana doesn't manage custom headers and the config [server.custom_response_headers] doesn't works either. So the solution is to use Nginx as reverse proxy.
grafana.conf:
if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' '*' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'x-grafana-org-id,x-grafana-user-id, Sec-Fetch-Site,Sec-Fetch-Mode,Sec-Fetch-Dest,Connection,Origin,Referer,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Request-Method,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Accept,Host,Content-Type,Authorization,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,Cache-Control,Content-Type' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
  add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
  return 204;
}

add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;


You can try a chrome extension called "Allow CORS"
